# How Can I move from one fragment to new fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to move to another fragment by clicking on a button. the current fragment named as FirstFragment and the target fragment named as AttendanceFragment. When I run the app it just crashed.
This is the code of the current fragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
*/
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {


public FirstFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

    Button btn1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    AttendanceFragment fragment = new AttendanceFragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.register_attendance, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            }
    );
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: post the exception stacktrace

Comment: What is the stacktrace? @Krish

Comment: crash log from logcat in android studio.

Comment: register_attendance what is this id? is this the container id?

Comment: I see no binding of this view **register_attendance**

Comment: is `R.id.register_attendance` your fragment container?

Comment: **register_attendance ** is the id that I built in the main drawer in of the navigation menu @AvishekDas

Comment: <item
            android:id="@+id/register_attendance"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_verified_user_black_24dp"
            android:title="Register Attendance" />

Comment: put the log with your error

Comment: @SanjogShrestha

Comment: What should be instead of register_attendance ? @SanjogShrestha

Comment: This id should be the container id where you place your fragment

Comment: Can you please show me an example ?@AvishekDas

Comment: @Ali replace `R.id.register_attendance` with the `R.id` of `FirstFragment`

Answer (score 1):

> Make an interface.

```
public interface FragmentChangeListener{
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment); 
}
```

> Implements your parent activity with this interface.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FragmentChangeListener {
         @Override
         public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();;     
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(mContainerId, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.toString());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();   
    }
}
```

> Call this method from Fragments like this.

```
//In your fragment - call this method from onClickListener
public void showOtherFragment(){
       Fragment fragment=new NewFragmentName();
       FragmentChangeListener listener = (FragmentChangeListener)getActivity();
       listener.replaceFragment(fragment); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Communicating with other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

There you can find elegant version of solution posted by `@Sanjog Shrestha`. You should register you callback in `onAttach(Activity activity)` and unregister it in `onDetach()`. You better be sure that `Activity` implements interface defined by yourself.